# Group Data Table messages using a field Graylog

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I have a Data Table connected to a stream where I receive the connections to the services. A field in the entering messages has a URL with the format domain.com/service/client_id, and I visualized them alongside other insights, resulting in something like:

- domain.com/service1/client1      Insight1       Insight2
- domain.com/service1/client2      Insight1       Insight2
- domain.com/service1/client3      Insight1       Insight2
- domain.com/service1/client4      Insight1       Insight2

The problem comes when I try to group them in a single field related to the service, like:

- domain.com/service1/             Insight1       Insight2
- domain.com/service2/             Insight1       Insight2

Is there a way to achieve this? I have been searching and nothing has helped me out so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [concat](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/functions#concat) function in a pipeline to concatenate multiple fields in a new field, like this (based on the example shown in the documentation):

```rust
let concat_field1 = concat(to_string($message.url)," ");

let concat_field2 = concat(concat_field1, " ");

let concat_field3 = concat(concat_field2, to_string($message.insight1));

let concat_field4 = concat(concat_field3, " ");

let concat_field5 = concat(concat_field4, to_string($message.insight2));

set_field("concat_field", concat_field5);
```